# Excel - Gantt Chart - Using Workday function - Workers Holidays

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Good Afternoon,

I´ve developed a **Gantt Grath** on excel based on the `workday()` function to assess the end date of a task based on an inputted start date and duration. I´m now trying to improve that function by providing the annual leave days of each worker, based on a table where those days are marked with an "x" for each worker (please see the **IMAGE 1** below).

I´ve worked the formula below. This formula looks for the worker name on the first column of the table, using a standard `index() + match()` pair and returns an array based on the days marked with an "x". That array is than used on the *holidays field* of the `workday()` function.

```
=WORKDAY($G$23,$H$23,IF(INDEX($B$8:$BA$18,MATCH($F$23,$B$8:$B$18,0),)="x",$C$7:$BA$7,"0"))
```

The problem that I´m having is that the `workday()` function does not count with the start date as a workday. As you can see on the second image, a task starting on the **02/10/2020** with a **3 day duration**, and 2 day leave by the worker on the **05/10/2020 and 06/10/2020** should end on the **08/10/2020 and not 07/10/2020.** (weekends, shown in yellow, are automatically disregarded by the formula).

I´ve already tried doing (-1) on the start date / duration added on the `workday()` but that just created other problems.

Can anyone help me in figuring out a solution for this problem. Thank you :)

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]